# Using Regex to extract multiple words from string with a known prefix

Tags: regex

I have the following input

```
 Obvious directions are:
  west, east, southeast, south.
```

... and would like the following output:

`west`
`east`
`southeast`
`south`

What would be the magical regex that'd do that for me?

I've gotten as far as extracting the first token, `west`, so thinking that I need a multiplier/recursor/something-or-other, but cannot for the life of me find what.

```
(?<= Obvious directions are:\s+)(\w+)(?=[,\.])
```

Comment: Close: `(?<=Obvious directions are:[^.]*?)\w+`, see https://regex101.com/r/hAjl2F/1. No recursion required.

Comment: Thank you [Ryszard Czech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11329890/ryszard-czech)! You've expanded my knowledge in Regex! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
(?<=Obvious directions are:[^.]*?)\w+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/hAjl2F/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Obvious directions       'Obvious directions are:'
    are:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.]*?                   any character except: '.' (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```